# php calculation not correct

Tags: php, checkbox

I have gotten rid of the errors with the help of others but for some reason the calculations are not going through, does anyone have any thoughts?

```
</head>   
<body>
<?php
if  (($_POST['lastname'] == NULL) || ($_POST['quantity'] == NULL) || 
    !isset($_POST['numberofrooms']) || !isset($_POST['smokingpreference'])) 
{
echo "<h1>Please return to the form and fill out completely</h1>";
}    
else
{
?>
<h1>Thanks for the order, <?php echo $_POST['lastname']; ?> Family.</h1>
<h1>Your reservation for  <?php echo $_POST['quantity']; ?> Night/s </h1>
<h1>With <?php echo $_POST['numberofrooms']; ?> room/s</h1>
<h1>And a room type of <?php echo $_POST['smokingpreference']; ?> </h1>    
<h1>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['pets']))
{
    echo  'With Pets';
}
if (isset($_POST['breakfast']))
{
    echo ' and Breakfast Buffet';
}
?>
<h1/>
<h1>Your total due will be: <?php echo $_POST['$total']; ?> </h1>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<h1>
  <?php
    if ($_POST['numberofrooms'] == "1")
    {
    $subtotal = ($_POST['quantity'] * 250);
    }
    elseif ($_POST['numberofrooms'] == "2")
    {
    $subtotal = ($_POST['quantity'] * 350);
    }
    else   //isset($_POST['numberofrooms']) == "3")
    {
    $subtotal = ($_POST['quantity'] * 425);
    }

    $breakfast = 25;    
    if (isset($_POST['breakfast']))
    {
    $subtotal = ($_POST['quantity'] * $breakfast);
    }       
    $smoke = 500;
    if ($_POST['smokingpreference'] == 'smoking')
    {
    $subtotal = $subtotal + $smoke;
    }       
    $pets = 200;
    if (isset($_POST['pets']))
    {
    $total = $subtotal + $pets;
    }

}    
?>
</h1>
</body>
</html>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="hw3.php">
  <h1>  Vacation Rental
  </h1>
  <p>Last Name:
    <label for="lastname"></label>
    <input name="lastname" type="text" id="lastname" size="18" maxlength="18" />
  </p>
  <p>Number of Nights Staying: 
    <label for="quantity"></label>
    <input name="quantity" type="text" id="quantity" size="3" maxlength="3" />
  </p>
  <p>Number Of Rooms: 

    <label>
      <br />
      <input type="radio" name="numberofrooms" value="1" id="NumberofRooms_0" />
    1</label>
     - $250.00 Per Night<br />
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="numberofrooms" value="2" id="NumberofRooms_1" />
      2</label>
- $350.00 Per Night <br />
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="numberofrooms" value="3" id="NumberofRooms_2" />
      3</label>
  - $425.00 Per Night</p>
  <p>Smoking or Non-Smoking Room: 
    <label>
      <br />
      <input type="radio" name="smokingpreference" value="smoking" id="SmokingPreference_0" />
    Smoking</label>
    - Add $500.00
    <br />
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="smokingpreference" value="nonsmoking" id="SmokingPreference_1" />
      Non-Smoking</label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="pets" id="pets" />
    <label for="pets">Pets</label>
  - Add $200.00</p>
  <p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="breakfast" id="breakfast" />
    <label for="breakfast">Breakfast Buffet</label> 
  - Add $25.00 Per Room</p>
  <p>
    <label>
      <input type="reset" name="reset" id="reset" value="Reset" />
      <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
    </label>
    <br />
  </p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I cannot seem to wrap my head around how I should go about getting my outputs, as my syntax is fine, but I keep getting errors. Obviously the user needs to be able to select any combination and get the correct output, but I cannot even find the cause of the error as syntactically it's fine. I will add the html portion as well.

```
</head>

<body>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="hw3.php">
  <h1>  Vacation Rental
  </h1>
  <p>Last Name:
    <label for="lastname"></label>
    <input name="lastname" type="text" id="lastname" size="18" maxlength="18" />
  </p>
  <p>Number of Nights Staying: 
    <label for="quantity"></label>
    <input name="quantity" type="text" id="quantity" size="3" maxlength="3" />
  </p>
  <p>Number Of Rooms: 

    <label>
      <br />
      <input type="radio" name="numberofrooms" value="1" id="NumberofRooms_0" />
    1</label>
     - $250.00 Per Night<br />
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="numberofrooms" value="2" id="NumberofRooms_1" />
      2</label>
- $350.00 Per Night <br />
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="numberofrooms" value="3" id="NumberofRooms_2" />
      3</label>
  - $425.00 Per Night</p>
  <p>Smoking or Non-Smoking Room: 
    <label>
      <br />
      <input type="radio" name="smokingpreference" value="smoking" id="SmokingPreference_0" />
    Smoking</label>
    - Add $500.00
    <br />
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="smokingpreference" value="nonsmoking" id="SmokingPreference_1" />
      Non-Smoking</label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="pets" id="pets" />
    <label for="pets">Pets</label>
  - Add $200.00</p>
  <p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="breakfast" id="breakfast" />
    <label for="breakfast">Breakfast Buffet</label> 
  - Add $25.00 Per Room</p>
  <p>
    <label>
      <input type="reset" name="reset" id="reset" value="Reset" />
      <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
    </label>
    <br />
  </p>
</form>
</body>
</html>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Vacation Rental Response Form</title>
</head>

<body>

<?php

if  (($_POST['lastname'] == NULL) || ($_POST['quantity'] == NULL) || 
    !isset($_POST['numberofrooms']) || !isset($_POST['smokingpreference'])) 
{
echo "<h1>Please return to the form and fill out completely</h1>";
}

else
{
?>
<h1>Thanks for the order, <?php echo $_POST['lastname']; ?> Family.</h1>
<h1>Your Reservation For  <?php echo $_POST['quantity']; ?> Night/s </h1>
<h1>With <?php echo $_POST['numberofrooms']; ?> Room/s</h1>
<h1>With A Room Type Of <?php echo $_POST['smokingpreference']; ?> </h1>
<h1>With/Without <?php echo $_POST['pets']; ?> </h1>
<h1>And <?php echo $_POST['breakfast']; ?> </h1>
<h1>Your Total Due Will Be: <?php echo $_POST['$sub1']; ?> </h1>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<h1>
  <?php
    if (isset($_POST['numberofrooms']) == "1")
    {
    $sub1 = ($_POST['quantity'] * 250);
    }
    elseif (isset($_POST['numberofrooms']) == "2")
    {
    $sub2 = ($_POST['quantity'] * 350);
    }
    else   //isset($_POST['numberofrooms']) == "3")
    {
    $sub3 = ($_POST['quantity'] * 425);
    }

    $breakfast = 25;    
    if (isset($_POST['breakfast']))
    {
    $sub1 = $sub1 * $breakfast;
    $sub2 = $sub2 * $breakfast;
    $sub3 = $sub3 * $breakfast;
    }

    $smoke = 500;
    if (isset($_POST['smokingpreference']))
    {
    $sub1 = $sub1 * $smoke;
    $sub2 = $sub2 * $smoke;
    $sub3 = $sub3 * $smoke;
    }

    $pets = 200;
    if (isset($_POST['pets']))
    {
    $sub1 = $sub1 * $pets;
    $sub2 = $sub2 * $pets;
    $sub3 = $sub3 * $pets;
    }


}

?>
</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Put the error message you're seeing in the post

Comment: So exactly what errors are you getting? Believe it or not, the actual message can occasionally be useful for diagnosing the problem.... though my guess is that you're being told that `$_POST['lastname']`, etc aren't set

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: pets in

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: breakfast in 
Notice: Undefined index: $sub1 in

Comment: I have the feeling I do not have the calculations portion done correctly, I know that they should be in a loop, but cannot get them to work, correctly.

Comment: Ray, I just put the errors I'm getting on

Comment: There are types of things PHP will emit errors, warnings, etc for other than syntax errors.  For example if you're trying to use a variable that doesn't exist yet.  PHP will automatically create a variable for you if you haven't initialised it but it will also say "Hey guy, you're trying to use a variable here that I've not seen yet. It might be something you need to look at".  That what the notice is.

Comment: GordonM, Thank you, I will look into it and see if I can find out if that's the issue.

Comment: I just updated this as there were a few changes, but my calculations are still not showing up correctly, any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that your are trying to access indexes in your `$_POST` array that are no there:

`<h1>With/Without <?php echo $_POST['pets']; ?> </h1>`

The element for `pets` is a checkbox, if it is not checked, you will not get a pets element in `$_POST`. So something like this would be better:

`<h1>With/Without <?php echo isset($_POST['pets']) ? 'With' : 'Without'; ?> </h1>`

Comment: dan08, I ill change that now, do you have any good thoughts on the most efficient way to get a total?

Comment: Idk, that might be another question, but your if statement are wrong `isset($_POST['numberofrooms']) == "1"` doesn't make sense `isset` return a bool, and `"1"` will be true, so these are always true if the index is set, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: good catch dan08, I have been pecking away at this all day here and there, and those are the type of slip ups I make all the time, just fixed it, thanks again !